# How to keep zoom setting permanent for each website in Vivaldi?

Tags: zoom, vivaldi

Say I want to zoom Stack Exchange at 120%, Reddit at 130%, Google at 100%. I do that in Vivaldi, and after I close the tab and reopen it, the scale is reset to 100%. The only way I can force it to be zoom is via Setting → Webpage → Default Webpage Zoom:

[image: vivaldi_2019-02-19_15-31-04.png]

But this zooms every page I visit. I want it to be zoomed manually, but the manual should be permanent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option *Use Tab Zoom* doesn't describe what it does clearly to me. Uncheck it and you are good.

[image]